# How is anomalous voting detected?

Tags: support, reputation, voting, up-votes, behavior

Sooner or later, a user may see that his answers are getting a lot of up-votes, then he gets a large negative reputation change labelled "voting corrected". This is because a user has voted on the answers in a short period of time, and then the system detects it and deletes the votes. Obviously, this is to protect the site from scripts, sock puppetry, or from people sorting answers by author, not content.

I have heard that you should avoid "five votes in a row", but how exactly is unusual voting behaviour detected? Is the exact algorithm classified?

Comment: I missed those duplicates. Should I delete my question?

Comment: Probably not necessary. If you missed the duplicates, then others might, too. If they use search terms that will find your post but not the duplicate, they now have a path to get to the information they want.

Comment: No. Leave it. Duplicates make good signposts to find questions.

Comment: Not everyone seem to agree with that. Deleting it when it drops below -6

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is classified. Otherwise it would be very easy to cheat your way around it.

From [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me?rq=1):

> **How does the system detect voting fraud?**
>
> Every night around 03:00 UTC, a voting fraud detection script is run that looks for patterns such as these. It basically looks for users who have upvoted another user many times. The number is fairly low within a given amount of time (**the exact mechanics are kept secret**). When the system detects this pattern, all of the votes cast from that user to the user affected are reversed and it prints a "voting corrected" statement in the affected user's reputation history to indicate what has occurred.